# when foreign key points to something else, move other data as well

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

Suppose you have the following models.

```
Book has Articles (Article has foreign key to Book)

Article has Images (Article has upto #max number of images)

Image also has a foreign key to Book.
```

(**edit** Certain images are included in the book but not owned by article)

Say you moved an article from book1 to book2.

You'd like to images in the article to point to book2 as well.

What's the preferred way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data model is unnecessary complicated. You should avoid such solutions. But if you have to live with this, you can use trigger before update on `articles`, e.g.

```
create function trigger_before_update_on_articles()
...
    if new.book_id <> old.book_id then
        update images set book_id = new.book_id
        where article_id = new.article_id
...
```

To normalize the model you can use `dummy` articles containing only images for a book.

Answer (score 1):

The perfect way would be not to have such a relationship, because it breaks data normalization rules https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

If you need it for performance reasons, than it doesn't make a lot of sence: indexes on foreign keys will do the lookup in 3 tables quite fast anyway. Such scheme is only useful in static tables where you are not supposed to modify anything. In this case it surely will save you some time.

Comment: sorry, I made an edit which might explain why I need image -> book relation. You might still say I 'm still violating something, please let me know how I can make it better.

Comment: Probably, making two separate relations: book_image and article_image will be the best way.