# database schema suggestion for book - article - image

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, schema

I have the following models.

```
Book has Articles (Article has foreign key to Book)

Article has Images (Article has upto #max number of foreign keys to images, Article have #max number of foreign key to images. which maybe null)

Furthermore I have Book - Image relation 
because certain images are included in the book but not owned by article
```

I made the models to answer fast to queries such as

- Give me images for an article.
- Give me images for a book (sorted bytime, paginated if needed)

People suggested I have a bad modeling. 
([when foreign key points to something else, move other data as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648961/when-foreign-key-points-to-something-else-move-other-data-as-well))

Want to know better alternative schema.

Comment: It's "schema". Also, you should have a max number of anything.  You need an article-image relationship table as well.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I edited OP slightly. Article has #max number of foreign key field (some of them might be null) to Image. Is having article-image table better? why?

Comment: Same schema definition for both MySQL and Postgresql? A tricky one...

Comment: @jarlh: shouldn't have included mysql nor postgresql as tags? :(

Comment: Since this is a data modeling question, the database engine doesn't matter.  If this were my database, I'd add a default record in the Article with a name like, "Not an Article".  Then you could assign images without real articles to that record and get rid of your book-image relation.  Also, if it's possible for an article to appear in more than one book, you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for the simple solution of (assuming postgresql database):

```
create table book (
  id integer primary key
);

create table article (
  id integer primary key,
  id_book integer references book(id)
);

create table image (
  id integer primary key,
  id_article integer references article(id),
  id_book integer references book(id),
  check ((id_article is null or id_book is null) and
    (id_article is not null or id_book is not null))
);
```

Check constraint does not allow for image to be assigned to both article or book.

- If image comes from article => `id_article` filled
- If from book only (not from article) => `id_book` filled

> Give me images for a book

```
select *
from book b
left join 
 (select *, id_book as book from image where id_article is null 
  union all
  select i.*, a.id_book as book from article a join image i on i.id_article=a.id) i on i.book = b.id;
```

Comment: what about, `sorted bytime, paginated` ?

Comment: @eugene, just add `order by time limit <limit> offset <offset>` to my query. Wouldn't it be sufficient?